# Regularity conditions hint

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Consider a well-defined function $\psi(x,\theta)$. Assume that it is a smooth function, differentiable, has a finite expectation and a finite second moment. $E\dfrac{\partial \psi(X,\theta)}{\partial \theta} \neq 0$ and is finite as well. The text book then provides the following hint:
$E \sup \biggl({\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left|\dfrac{\partial\psi(X_i,\theta)}{\partial\theta} - \dfrac{\partial\psi(X_i,\theta(P))}{\partial\theta(P)}\right|:|\theta-\theta(P)|\leq \epsilon_n}\biggr) \leq E \sup \biggl({\left|\dfrac{\partial\psi(X_1,\theta)}{\partial\theta} - \dfrac{\partial\psi(X_1,\theta(P))}{\partial\theta(P)}\right|:|\theta-\theta(P)|\leq \epsilon_n}\biggr)$

EDIT: Assume $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are iid random variables.
The parameter $\theta(P)$ is given by the solution of $\int{\psi(x) f(x,\theta) dx} = 0$, where as $\theta$ is a free variable.

How does the above relation hold? Does it hold all the time?

Comment: You use $\theta$ in two distinct ways, so please explain the distinction between "$\theta$" and "$\theta(P).$"  Without any context we can't even guess.

Comment: Clarified this a bit. $\theta(P)$ is the minimum contrast estimator whereas $\theta$ is the parameter we are trying to estimate.

Answer (score 3):

Written in that way, it seems complicated.  But what the hint really says is just the following simple [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207335/prove-supfg-le-sup-f-sup-g):
\begin{align}
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta}(f(\theta) + g(\theta)) \leq 
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta}f(\theta) + \sup_{\theta \in \Theta}g(\theta),
\end{align}
for any real functions $f, g$ and non-empty set $\Theta$.

Now use the linearity of expectation and the i.i.d. assumption of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$.

Comment: Added a relevant post at Math.SE. We use this quite often but I wonder whether it has any name to be used as reference. Or just the generic name "$\sup$ inequality".

Comment: @User1865345 Thanks for your edit.  It would be helpful.